# "proceedings" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I have created [proceedings](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proceedings) tag while i'm newbie to the tag thing.  Is it identical to some other tags? I believe most of the questions related to conference publications will have this tag (i.e., [conference](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conference), [journals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journals)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not particularly against a [proceedings](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proceedings) tag, but I'm not sure how relevant it is for the question you tagged. Indeed, intuitively, such a tag would rather identify the questions about the actual proceedings of a conference (how to make them, what should be in them, how to access them, etc). The question you tagged seems to be rather about the journal/conference difference.

Perhaps a good thing when you create a new tag is to provide the definition with it, so that it's clear what you mean by that tag.